Rank-2 tensor multiplication discrepancy
Given any tensor $A \,\text{and}\, B$. (Not necessarily symmetric or anti-symmetric)
$$A^{\mu}_{\,\,\,\nu}B_{\mu}^{\,\,\,\rho} = C_{\nu}^{\,\,\rho} \,\,\, \text{or} \,\,\,  C^{\rho}_{\,\,\,\nu}\,\,\,?\tag1 $$
Which one is true?
I've tried writing $A$ and $B$ as a sum of symmetric and anti-symmetric tensors but I still had the same discrepancy. (Overbar means anti-symmetric, otherwise means symmetric)
$$A^{\mu}_{\,\,\,\nu}B_{\mu}^{\,\,\,\rho} = (a^{\mu}_{\,\,\,\nu} + \bar{a}^{\mu}_{\,\,\,\nu})(b^{\,\,\,\rho}_{\mu} + \bar{b}^{\,\,\,\rho}_{\mu})$$
$$= a^{\mu}_{\,\,\,\nu}b^{\,\,\,\rho}_{\mu}+a^{\mu}_{\,\,\,\nu}\bar{b}^{\,\,\,\rho}_{\mu}+\bar{a}^{\mu}_{\,\,\,\nu}b^{\,\,\,\rho}_{\mu}+\bar{a}^{\mu}_{\,\,\,\nu}\bar{b}^{\,\,\,\rho}_{\mu}.$$
I could write this expression in two ways;
$$a^{\,\,\,\mu}_{\nu}b^{\,\,\,\rho}_{\mu}+a^{\,\,\,\mu}_{\nu}\bar{b}^{\,\,\,\rho}_{\mu}-\bar{a}^{\,\,\,\mu}_{\nu}b^{\,\,\,\rho}_{\mu}-\bar{a}^{\,\,\,\mu}_{\nu}\bar{b}^{\,\,\,\rho}_{\mu}$$
$$=C^{\,\,\,\rho}_{\nu},$$
and
$$a^{\mu}_{\,\,\,\nu}b^{\rho}_{\,\,\,\mu}-a^{\mu}_{\,\,\,\nu}\bar{b}^{\rho}_{\,\,\,\mu}+\bar{a}^{\mu}_{\,\,\,\nu}b^{\rho}_{\,\,\,\mu}-\bar{a}^{\mu}_{\,\,\,\nu}\bar{b}^{\rho}_{\,\,\,\mu}$$
$$=C^{\rho}_{\,\,\,\nu}.$$
Where is my mistake, if there is any? Is there even a difference between $C_{\nu}^{\,\,\rho}$ and $C^{\rho}_{\,\,\,\nu}$ in this case?

Usually a distinction is only made in how covariant indices are ordered among themselves and also how contravariant indices are ordered among themselves but not how covariant and contravariant indices are ordered relative to each other. Often, in notation they're just put on top of each other, so instead of $C_{\nu}^{,,\rho}$ or $C^{\rho}{,,,\nu}$ you can just write $C^{\rho}{\nu}$.

@QuantumWiz That's fine only for tensors that you never raise/lower the indices of via the metric. Once you do however, you have to keep track of the horizontal placement. Otherwise lowered indices may "float up" to places where they don't belong, and vice versa, leaving you with a tensor which looks the same but isn't. See my answer here for details.

@Amit Yeah, if you have a metric tensor, then you also have a natural mapping between the vector space and its dual space so then there isn't really any difference between covariant and contravariant indices. If you don't have such metric or a dot product or an inner product or anything like that which would provide a natural mapping between the vector space and its dual, then the covariant indices and contravariant indices are "wholly separate" (for a lack of a better wording) and there's no reason to care how they're ordered relative to each other.

@Amit Actually, now that I've thought a bit more about it, I think even raising/lowering indices with a metric tensor shouldn't create a problem. If you're using a metric tensor, all the indices are labelled so there should be no confusion about the order. You might still prefer if the covariant and cotravariant indices are explicitly ordered relative to each other for the sake of extra clarity, but that's just a matter of taste, not an absolute requirement.

@QuantumWiz I think you're missing the point that labels can easily change on contraction, unless you explicitly write out the contraction in a way to avoid that. If you do however yes I agree, it's a valid way to keep track of which index is which. But I think the other option of staggered indices is simpler and less error prone

But I'm not sure how changing labels would result in an error. Let's say I have a tensor $A^{i}{j}$ and a metric tensor $g{i,j}$ and I want to move lower of the indices of $A$. I could define the tensor with the lowered index e.g. $B_{i,j}=A^{k}{i} g{k,j}$ (so the lowered index becomes the second one) or alternatively $C_{i,j}=A^{k}{j} g{k,i}$ (so the lowered index becomes the first one). Both are valid expressions and there's no error as long as I don't confuse $B$ and $C$ with each other. I could still make the same choice even if the indices of $A$ were explicitly ordered.

@QuantumWiz Now you're adding another labeling convention, that we normally don't use. We want to use the same letter for a tesnor, even when we raise/lower its indices.

@Amit If you mean B and C, I just used them because they are slightly different tensors (reflecting a different choice of the order of the indices). In fact, they're transposes of each other.

Ultimately, I don't think you've given enough information to uniquely specify an answer, so this boils down to a matter of convention. It also usually won't matter in a practical calculation if you are consistent with your conventions. But given what you've written I think $C_\nu^{\ \ \ \rho}$ would be the most natural way to define $C$.
Let's remember that tensors are multi-linear maps from tensor products of a vector space and its dual to the real numbers (at least for GR). So ultimately the meaning of any expression with free indices, is that you can convert that expression to a number by contracting it with an appropriate dual tensor.
To see what I mean, first let's define a tensor $X_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}$. One way to express what this tensor means is that if I contract it with a set of vectors like $a^\mu b^\nu c^\rho d^\sigma$, I will get a number:
$$
X_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma} a^\mu b^\nu c^\rho d^\sigma = r
$$
The Einstein summation convention lets me permute, say, $a^\mu$ and $b^\nu$ without changing $r$, and it lets me do a relabeling where I simultaneously change $\mu\rightarrow \nu$ and $\nu \rightarrow \mu$ everywhere in the above expression, but I cannot swap $\mu\leftrightarrow \nu$ only on $X$, or only on $ab$. In other words, $X_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}b^\nu a^\mu c^\rho d^\sigma = r \neq X_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma} b^\mu a^\nu c^\rho d^\sigma $.
Now let's define
$$
X_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma} = A_{\mu\nu} B_{\rho\sigma}
$$
You may be tempted to say that since $A_{\mu\nu}B_{\rho\sigma}=B_{\rho\sigma} A_{\mu\nu}$, that $X_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}=X_{\rho\sigma\mu\nu}$. However, this is not true, which you can see by staring at the definitions. In fact, even doing $A_{\mu\nu}B_{\rho\sigma}=B_{\rho\sigma}A_{\mu\nu}$ is a little trickier than it looks, which we'll see in a minute.
Now, we will raise, lower, and contract various indices to get your pattern:
$$
X^{\mu\ \ \ \ \ \ \sigma}_{\ \ \ \nu\mu} = A^\mu_{\ \ \ \nu} B_\mu^{\ \ \ \sigma}
$$
To disambiguate the meaning, we are going to consider a contraction with some arbitrary vectors/1-forms
$$
r = \left(X^{\mu\ \ \ \ \ \ \rho}_{\ \ \ \nu\mu} \right) a^\nu b_\rho = \left(A^\mu_{\ \ \ \nu} B_\mu^{\ \ \ \rho}\right) a^\nu b_\rho
$$
Now we want to define a new tensor $C$ that acts like $A^\mu_{\ \ \ \nu} B_\mu^{\ \ \ \rho}$.
Should it be
$$
\left(C_\nu^{\ \ \ \rho}\right)a^\nu b_\rho
$$
or
$$
\left(C^{\rho}_{\ \ \ \nu}\right)a^\nu b_\rho
$$
I would argue that the first definition is more natural. We started off by multiplying $X$ by $ab$, where $a$ is contracted to the first index and $b$ to the second index. To make the second definition equivalent to what we started with, we need to swap the indices that $a$ and $b$ are contracted to the second and first indices, respectively.
This ultimately reflects our choice to define $X=AB$. If we had defined $X=BA$, when we had gotten to this point, we would have thought that $C^\rho_{\ \ \nu}$ was the more natural choice. So what's going on?
If we want to be strict, then the order of indices from left to right in a tensor expression tells us which copy of the vector space or its dual we are referring to. $X_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}$ expanded out in basis one-forms $\hat{\omega}^\mu$ is
$$
\hat{X} = X_{\mu\nu\rho\sigma} \left[\hat{\omega^\mu} \otimes \hat{\omega^\nu} \otimes \hat{\omega^\rho}\otimes \hat{\omega^\sigma}\right]
$$
Since the tensor product doesn't commute, we have to choose whether under the decomposition $X=AB$, whether $A$ acts on the first two copies of the dual vector space in the tensor product, or the second two. Since you haven't specified how you originally intended to contract $A$ and $B$ with the underlying basis one forms, I don't think your question has a unique answer, although based on the notation I would say $AB$ is a more natural convention than $BA$, so $C_\nu^{\ \ \ \rho}$ is a more natural answer.
However, once you end up contracting all the indices, then you can permute $A$ and $B$ safely, since the indices contain the information about the pattern of contraction, since $A_{\mu\nu} B_{\rho\sigma} a^\mu b^\nu c^\rho d^\sigma = B_{\rho\sigma} A_{\mu\nu} a^\mu b^\nu c^\rho d^\sigma$. In practice, we often have in mind ultimately looking at individual components of tensors by doing an actual calculation, which amounts to contracting with specific vectors/one forms adapted to some coordinate system, so in practical calculations we can usually commute $A$ and $B$ without issues like this popping up.
Said a little differently, in practice a calculation would typically involve comparing two tensors, like
$$
A_{\mu\nu} B^{\mu\rho} = T_{\nu}^{\ \ \rho}
$$
Then the order of indices on $T$ would essentially fix how you are supposed to contract external vectors on the product $AB$. Or, said a little differently again, at some earlier point in the calculation when you introduced $AB$, there should be some way of contracting the indices with external vectors that makes it clear which index on $AB$ should be "first" and which one "second".

I agree that one should check what the transpose is doing when applied in some scalar product with arbitrary tensor say $D^\nu_\rho$. Then one would check if the result works for all $D^\nu_\rho$.

It doesn't matter how you define the new tensor $\mathbf{C}$, but the caveat is that if, as we often do, endow the underlying vector space with a metric tensor that allows us to raise and lower indices, both definitions will be mutually exclusive.
To see what I mean, consider a simpler case, where we are faced with two possibilities to define a $(1,1)$ tensor from a contravariant vector $A^i$ and a covariant vector $B_j$:
$$T^i{}_j := A^iB_j\tag{1}$$
$$T_j{}^i := B_jA^i\tag{2}$$
Now, suppose we choose definition $(1)$. We can then use the metric tensor to write:
$$g_{jk}g^{mi}T^k{}_m=T_j{}^i\tag{3}$$
So, we see that the mere existence of a metric, in fact forces $T_j{}^i$ to be computed as in $(3)$. Now, the important point is that this is not the same tensor as the one given by $(2)$. To see that, rewrite $(3)$ using our chosen definition $(1)$:
$$T_j{}^i=g_{jk}g^{mi}T^k{}_m=g_{jk}g^{mi}A^kB_m=A_jB^i\neq B_jA^i$$
So, the upshot is that while we are free to choose the horizontal index order when we define a new tensor like $\mathbf{C}$ in your question, this choice also inherently contradicts the validity of the other, alternative definitions.
This contradiction is simply due to the fact that the duality of vectors and covectors that we want to establish via the metric tensor, is not a simple transposition/permutation of the indices (or if you prefer to think of tensors as multilinear maps, it's not just a permutation of the parameter entries).
For one thing, the most basic observation is that the components of a contravariant vector, that can be written in terms of its covariant dual: $v^j=g^{ji}v_i$ are not simply the components of $v_i$ positioned in a "column" like we could naively think about the duality of column and row vectors in an Euclidean vector space.
For a more detailed explanation that goes into a lot more of the mathematical machinery behind this, see this answer by @peek-a-boo on Math.SE, to a related question. I do recommend reading his entire answer because it's very helpful in the context of this question. Here, I'll only quote the summary of his post, the upshot is clear despite admittedly lacking some context:

Now, the reason people make such a fuss about staggering indices and not mixing thing up is because

They never ever mean the tensors obtained by a simple permutation of the factors. So, they’re talking about the pair $F,\Phi$, not the pair $F,G$. (Often in Physics people say the pair $F,\Phi$ are “physically related” by the metric duality… but this is just jargon you can ignore).
They always use the same letter for the tensor, e.g $T$, and use the placement (up-down, and staggering) to keep track of which tensor specifically they’re talking about. So, rather than introducing two letters $F,\Phi$, they’ll simply say $T^a_{\,\,b}\neq T_b^{\,\,a}$.



The expression ${A^\mu}_\nu {B_\mu}^\rho$ only determines that there should be a lower $\nu$ and an upper $\rho$ (while the upper and lower $\mu$ cancel). It doesn't determine the order of them in the left-right direction.
You can define both ${C_\nu}^\rho$ and ${D^\rho}_\nu$ to equal that expression, i.e. ${C_\nu}^\rho = {D^\rho}_\nu = {A^\mu}_\nu {B_\mu}^\rho.$
